# Chart.js - Vertical crosshair (vertical annotation that moves with mouse) in line graph

Tags: momentjs, chart.js

I am using Chart.js and have been looking for a way to have a vertical annotation/crosshair in my graph.

I want this vertical line to move horizontally, following my mouse cursor when the cursor is in the graph.

How to create a vertical crosshair that changes its horizontal position based on the cursor movement using Chart.js?

Comment: Posting self-answered questions to offer a solution useful to the community is perfectly allowed and even encouraged on Stack Overflow. However, the question as it is currently stated is not very clear / explanatory, so it's usefulness is limited. If you could describe the problem to be solved a bit better, that would be definitely helpful.

Comment: @Pac0 I have edited it, is this still unclear?

Comment: It's better to me, but not sure if it will be for the reviewers in the "Reopen" review queue. I'm not usually fond of screenshots / graphics in question, but in this case I be in favor of such a illustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I've done it: I've created an annotation whose value I change with an `onmousemove` event on the canvas.

```
var annotation = {
    annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'vertical',
        scaleID: 'x-axis',
        borderColor: '#b6fcd5',
        borderWidth: 2
    }]
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("chart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx,
    {
    ...
    },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'x',
                intersect: false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    "id": 'x-axis',
                    type: 'time'
                }],
                ...
            },
            annotation: annotation
        }
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
    canvas.onmousemove = function (evt) {
        var points = myChart.getElementsAtXAxis(evt);
        annotation.annotations[0].value = new Date(myChart.config.data.labels[points[0]._index]);
        myChart.update();
    };
});
```